# Группировка ListView с виртуализацией

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp, windows-10-mobile

C# UWP Windows 10

Необходимо выводить список из нескольких десятков тысяч записей в группированном виде. Сейчас это реализовано как в примере MSDN через `CollectionViewSource` который является источником данных для `ListView`. Работает это очень хорошо, но проблема в том что сначала нужно эти записи загрузить в память из базы `SQLite`, что само по себе занимает очень много времени. Я нашел примеры как реализовать `ISupportIncrementalLoading`, что полностью решило бы мою проблему, но он не работает с группировкой.

Какие есть варианты решения подобной задачи?

Comment: Я по моему уже спрашивал у вас - как вы представляете себе сгруппированный лист с виртуализацией? Виртуализация годится для линейных списков, потому что от текущей позиции надо просто взять смещение. С группировкой получается ерунда - может появиться запись, которую надо добавить в уже просмотренный сектор, но его же уже никто не увидит. Делайте группировку на уровне модели и не изобретайте франкенштейна.

Comment: @Monk Я понимаю вашу точку зрения, но я в модели точно так же добавляю в группы новые записи, и UI их отображает по событию CollectionChanged. То же может быть и с группированным списком, мне бы даже подошел вариант инкремента не по записям, а по группам. В одной группе не более 20 записей, а в общем записей может быть десятки тысяч, держать это все в памяти явно не вариант...

Comment: Не сталкивался с задачей в таком виде, попробовал бы засунуть один листвью в другой. В верхнем уровне - с вируталиацией, группы, в нижнем - без неё, раз там до 20 элементов всего.

Comment: @Monk А это уже интересная идея, спасибо, попробую